# socket.io is not found with Express 4?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, express-4

I have been trying to get my client connected with my server,but chrome always print that

> GET http://localhost:30653/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)

I don't know where's the problem...

the express version is "4.13.4" and socket.io version is "1.4.5"

And here is my code:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var hbs = require('hbs');
var app=express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log("connected");
    socket.emit('open');
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 30653);
app.set('view engine','html');
app.engine('html',hbs.__express);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('chatroom');
});
app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log('this server is listening on port:'+app.get('port'));
});
```

client:

```
$(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:30653');
    socket.on('open',function(){
        console.log("open")
    });
    socket.on('system',function(json){
        console.log("system");
    });
});
```

any help is welcome!I'll be very appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `app.listen(...)` needs to be `server.listen(...)` because of the way you are creating your server as illustrated here: http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4.  The way you are doing it, socket.io is not hooked to the right server and thus is not serving the socket.io.js file for you.

You can do `app.listen()`, but only if you follow a different initialization procedure here: http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-the-express-framework

Comment: Great!   I replaced app.listen() with server.listen() and thus client find socket.io/socket.io.js. I make it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need use the below line of code in app.js after the line app.use(express.static('public'));

```
  app.use("/lib", express.static(path.join(__dirname,'node_modules')));
```

and then import in your client as below

```
   <script src='/lib/socket.io/socket.io.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: socket.io automatically installs a route for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` so this is not needed.